# Auto login by using HttpWebRequest

Tags: httpwebrequest, session-cookies, autologin

I'm writing a window application by C# to auto login & post topic to a website. I've tried to pass username & password as the method following but the responseText did not changed. I meant if I passed the incorrect username or password the responseText would be included the "Error text such: wrong password or username" or if I passed to right username & password the responseText would be included "Login successfully" but the responseText I received was like a original login page

Do you have any idea? Thank you so much

```
    private string Login()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        string cookieHeader = string.Empty;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username=abc@gmail.com&password=123");

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.vietnamworks.com/dang-nhap");

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.UserAgent = userAgent;

        request.Method = "POST";

        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string pageSource;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return pageSource;
    }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It seems that there is some authentication  token or cookies which are required upon posting the page back.